# JPA entity expression evaluator

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpql

Is there any possibility to evaluate if the JPA entity fulfils JPQL/RSQL expression using any libs or Hibernate without an active Entity Manager?

For example:

```
SampleEntity entity = ...;
boolean evaluationResult = new Criteria("id=gt=1").test(entity);
```

Answer (score 1):

You may just use this library: https://github.com/turkraft/spring-filter

It will let you run search queries such as:

> */search?filter=* **average**(ratings) **>** 4.5 **and** brand.name **in** ('audi', 'land rover') **and** (year **>** 2018 **or** km **<** 50000) and color **:** 'white' **and** accidents **is empty**

You can also run search queries even if you don't have an API, the library basically compiles a search input to JPA predicates.

Answer (score 0):

[Blaze-Expression](https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-expression#declarative-persistence-usage) is a library that implements a syntax similar to JPQL and supports expression evaluation/interpretation, as well as serialization to a Blaze-Persistence query builder.

See here for an example: https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-expression/blob/master/declarative/persistence/src/test/java/com/blazebit/expression/declarative/persistence/ModelTest.java